# KECCAK-256 Hash function in VB6 Or VBA

Tags: vb6, chilkat, hash-of-hashes, chilkat-email, chilkat-sshkey

### why keccak-256 is not the chilkat hash olgaritm ?

```
Dim crypt As New ChilkatCrypt2
crypt.EncodingMode = "hex_lower"
crypt.HashAlgorithm = **"keccak-256"???**
Dim bdSeed As New ChilkatBinData
success = bdSeed.AppendEncoded("43b337dec65a47b3362c9620a6e6ff39a1ddfa908abab1666c8a30a3f8a7ccccfc24a7914950b6405729a9313cec6ae5bb4a082f92d05ac49df4b6dd8387bfeb", "hex_lower")
MsgBox crypt.HashBdENC(bdSeed)
```

I wonder why this hash model does not exist in chilkat system?
Do you have any suggestion or function to VB6 for keccak hash?

Comment: It's called `sha3-256` in Chilkat and almost everywhere else. Keccak is the name given by its authors before becoming official sha3 hash.

Comment: The result of SHA3-256 is different from Keccak-256. I tried it and the answer of Chilkat was different

Comment: You are right actually. [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?897071-VB6-VBA-SHA-3-pure-VB-implementation-incl-HMAC) is a module for VB6/VBA which does both Keccak-256 and SHA3-256.